# Firefox linking to local Windows folders & Files

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, networking, google-chrome, windows-xp

I've tried this help: [Firefox Links to local or network pages do not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192080/firefox-links-to-local-or-network-pages-do-not-work)

AND: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Links_to_local_pages_do_not_work

I have ColdFusion app with an intranet. We have files that are coming off a network server path and a drive mapping. In Internet Explorer 8 the links work perfectly, either opening Windows Explorer or whatever application associated with that file (Eg, Word, Excel etc...).

I've tried everything: about:config, modifying javascript/user preferences, plugins all with no luck. When I click the link NOTHING happens. This issue is for both FireFox 3.6.12 and Chrome. IE 8 no problems.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Show us a link that isn't working.

Comment: Like I said, this is an Intranet site. Everything the site links to is internal, eg fileserver.recenter.colostate

Answer (score 0):

If it's Windows only, you could use a [custom protocol handler](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/noahc/archive/2006/10/19/register-a-custom-url-protocol-handler.aspx) for this that executes `explorer.exe <url>`

Be aware of the security implications, though, seeing as any application could feed you links containing the custom protocol.

Comment: the custom url protocol specifically asks you to code in .net.Also, needs much more work.

Comment: @Neeraj the custom URL protocol has nothing to do with .NET. See the updated link