# Cross-browser URL to windows share

Tags: html, internet-explorer, cross-browser, href, windows-share

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Firefox Links to local or network pages do not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192080/firefox-links-to-local-or-network-pages-do-not-work)

I want my servers location (SharePoint) wiki page to display server names and links to windows shares located there, i.e. `\\myserver1`

This works in IE:

```
<a href="file:///\\myserver1">myserver1</a>
```

but in FF - not.

How to implement cross-browser windows share link?

Comment: Is this inside an intranet? Do you control the client machines?

Comment: @Pekka: Yes, intranet servers. No access to client machines/browsers settings, only to my one :)

Comment: then I'm afraid this *may* be impossible. AFAIK (as pointed out in the dupe) local links are disabled by default in FF.