# How to show local picture in web page?

Tags: html

I need to show a picture on web page without uploading it. something like

```
 <img id="RuPic" src="file://localhost/D:/folder/image.jpg"/>
```

How to do that?

Comment: Just remove the `localhost/` and you should be good to go.

Comment: @Pekka: the browser will access the client D: drive?

Comment: @John yup, in the context of an image this should work fine. (IIRC, there are restrictions in place for local iframes for security reasons - and of course, you can never parse local documents due to the Same Origin Policy - but images should be okay.)

Comment: This will only work if the webpage is saved locally. Most browsers won't let a remote webpage embed a local file.

Comment: @Lèse @John I stand corrected: The latest Chrome, FF and IE indeed block images from local sources (FF since 1.5). @Artem this seems not possible any more.

Comment: @Pekka: Only `localhost` needs to be removed... there should be 3 forward slashes for it to work: `file:///D:/folder/image.jpg`.

Comment: @Pekka: yes, I just confirmed this. Works when saved locally, but not when served on localhost.

Comment: @Artem: you need to clarify your question: is the HTML file on the same PC as the picture you want to show?

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://superuser.com/questions/224500/how-to-display-local-images-in-chrome-using-file-protocol

Answer (score 18):

You can do that easily using `FileReader.readAsDataURL()`. The user chooses an image and you can display it without needing to upload it.

For more info see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL

Here is the code:

```js
function previewFile() {
    // Where you will display your image
    var preview = document.querySelector('img');
    // The button where the user chooses the local image to display
    var file = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
    // FileReader instance
    var reader  = new FileReader();

    // When the image is loaded we will set it as source of
    // our img tag
    reader.onloadend = function () {
      preview.src = reader.result;
    }

    
    if (file) {
      // Load image as a base64 encoded URI
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    } else {
      preview.src = "";
    }
  }
```

```html
  <input type="file" onchange="previewFile()"><br>
  <img src="" height="200" alt="Image preview...">
```

Answer (score 4):

Linking to local image files from remote HTML files used to be possible, but no longer is.

- In Firefox since version 1.5 (background and config options [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192080/firefox-links-to-local-or-network-pages-do-not-work))
- In Internet Explorer I *think* since Version 8 (I believe I have successfully done this in IE 7, but I can't find hard data)
- In Chrome probably since forever

See for example [this vulnerability report](https://www.greymagic.com/security/advisories/gm003-ie/) for why this is a good thing.

I don't think there is a workaround. You will just have to upload the image first.

Answer (score 0):

You must make a way to answer file requests and move your files near your project source. then make your addressing relative. This is my code which works fine for me:

```
package ir.cclever.example;

import java.awt.List;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class WellCloseWebServer {

    public class clientInfo{
        public String ip;
        public Date visitTime;
    }

    static ArrayList<clientInfo> clients = new ArrayList<clientInfo>();

    public  void start() throws IOException {
        ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(8181,1000);
        System.out.println("Webserver starting up on port 8181");
        System.out.println("Waiting for connection");

        //==========================regex
        String pathRegex = "(?<=GET /).+?(?= HTTP)";

        Pattern pathPattern = Pattern.compile(pathRegex);
        //==========================/regex

        try {
            while (true) {
                Socket socket = listener.accept();
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

                String wholeRequest = "";
                String line;

                String requestHeaders = in.readLine();
                wholeRequest = wholeRequest.concat(requestHeaders + "\n<br>");

                while(!(line = in.readLine()).equals("")){
                    wholeRequest = wholeRequest.concat(line + "\n<br>");
                }

                wholeRequest = wholeRequest.concat("\n<br/>\n<br/>\nClient IP Address : " + socket.getRemoteSocketAddress().toString());
                wholeRequest = wholeRequest.concat("\n<br/>\n<br/>\nClient Opened Port : " + ((Integer)socket.getPort()).toString());

                clientInfo newClient = new clientInfo();
                newClient.ip = socket.getRemoteSocketAddress().toString();
                newClient.visitTime = new Date();
                clients.add(newClient);

                Matcher pathMatcher = pathPattern.matcher(requestHeaders);

                Boolean anyPath = pathMatcher.find();

                System.out.println("Connection, sending data to request : " + requestHeaders);
                try {
                    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                    if (!anyPath) {
                        JustHello(out);
                    }
                    else {
                        String directory = pathMatcher.group();

                        System.out.println(directory);

                        if (directory.toString().equals("pic")) {
                            JustPic(out);
                        }
                        else if(directory.toString().startsWith("server/")){
                            getFile(directory,dos,true);
                        }
                        else if(directory.toString().endsWith("jpg")){
                            getFile(directory,dos,false);
                        }
                        else if(directory.toString().equals("my.aspx")){
                            mirror(out,wholeRequest);
                        }
                        else if(directory.toString().equals("clients.html")){
                            WholeClients(out);
                        }
                        else{
                            errorPage(out);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    socket.close();
                }
            }
        }
        finally {
            listener.close();
        }
    }

    private void InvalidRequestMethod(PrintWriter out, String string) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        out.println("HTTP/1.0 404 NOT FOUND");
        out.println("Content-Type: text/html");
        out.println("Server: Bot");
        // this blank line signals the end of the headers
        out.println("");
        out.flush();
        // Send the HTML page
        out.print("<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<head>\n<title>Just GET</title>\n<meta charset=\"UTF-8\">\n</head>\n<body>\nInvalid request mehtod! : "+ string +"\n</body>\n</html>");
        out.flush();
    }

    private void errorPage(PrintWriter out) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        out.println("HTTP/1.0 404 NOT FOUND");
        out.println("Content-Type: text/html");
        out.println("Server: Bot");
        // this blank line signals the end of the headers
        out.println("");
        out.flush();
        // Send the HTML page
        out.print("<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<head>\n<title>Error 404 NOT FOUND!</title>\n<meta charset=\"UTF-8\">\n</head>\n<body>\nContent not found on server!\n</body>\n</html>");
        out.flush();
    }

    private void WholeClients(PrintWriter out) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        out.println("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
        out.println("Content-Type: text/html");
        out.println("Server: Bot");
        // this blank line signals the end of the headers
        out.println("");
        out.flush();
        // Send the HTML page
        out.print("<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<head>\n<title>Whole Clients</title>\n<meta charset=\"UTF-8\">\n</head>\n<body>\n");
        Integer i=0;
        for (clientInfo item : clients) {
            i++;
            out.print("<br/>\n"+i.toString()+") ip : " + item.ip + " | visit time : " + item.visitTime.toString());
        }
        out.print("\n</body>\n</html>");
        out.flush();
    }

    private void mirror(PrintWriter out, String requestHeaders) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        out.println("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
        out.println("Content-Type: text/html");
        out.println("Server: Bot");
        // this blank line signals the end of the headers
        out.println("");
        out.flush();
        // Send the HTML page
        out.print("<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<head>\n<title>My Info</title>\n<meta charset=\"UTF-8\">\n</head>\n<body>\n" +
                requestHeaders.toString() +
                "\n</body>\n</html>");
        out.flush();
    }

    private void getFile(String directory, DataOutputStream os, boolean b) {
        String CRLF = "\r\n";
        // Open the requested file.
        String fileName = directory;
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        boolean fileExists = true;
        try {
        //(new File(fileName)).mkdirs();
        fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        fileExists = false;
        }

        // Construct the response message.
        String statusLine = null;
        String contentTypeLine = null;
        String entityBody = null;
        if (fileExists) {
        statusLine = "200 OK" + CRLF;
        contentTypeLine = "Content-type: " + 
                contentType( fileName ) + CRLF;
        } else {
        statusLine = "404 NOT FOUND" + CRLF;
        contentTypeLine = "Content Not Found!" + CRLF;
        entityBody = "<HTML>" + 
            "<HEAD><TITLE>Not Found</TITLE></HEAD>" +
            "<BODY>Not Found</BODY></HTML>";
        }

        // Send the status line.
        try {
            if (b) {
                os.writeBytes(statusLine);
                // Send the content type line.
                os.writeBytes(contentTypeLine);
                // Send a blank line to indicate the end of the header lines.
                os.writeBytes(CRLF);
            }
            // Send the entity body.
            if (fileExists) {
            sendBytes(fis, os);
            fis.close();
            } else {
            os.writeBytes("File DNE: Content Not Found!");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static String contentType(String fileName) {
        if(fileName.endsWith(".htm") || fileName.endsWith(".html")) {
            return "text/html";
        }
        if(fileName.endsWith(".jpeg") || fileName.endsWith(".jpg")) {
        return "image/jpeg";
        }
        if(fileName.endsWith(".gif")) {
        return "image/gif";
        }
        if(fileName.endsWith(".png")) {
            return "image/png";
            }
        if(fileName.endsWith(".js")) {
            return "text/javascript";
            }
        if(fileName.endsWith(".css")) {
            return "text/stylesheet";
            }

        return "application/octet-stream";
        }

    private static void sendBytes(FileInputStream fis, OutputStream os) 
        throws Exception {
        // Construct a 1K buffer to hold bytes on their way to the socket.
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytes = 0;

        // Copy requested file into the socket's output stream.
        while((bytes = fis.read(buffer)) != -1 ) {
            os.write(buffer, 0, bytes);
            }
        }

    private void JustHello(PrintWriter out) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        out.println("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
        out.println("Content-Type: text/html");
        out.println("Server: Bot");
        // this blank line signals the end of the headers
        out.println("");
        out.flush();
        // Send the HTML page
        out.print("<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<head>\n<title>Just Hello</title>\n<meta charset=\"UTF-8\">\n</head>\n<body>\nHello World\n</body>\n</html>");
        out.flush();
    }

    private void JustPic(PrintWriter out) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        out.println("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
        out.println("Content-Type: text/html");
        out.println("Server: Bot");
        // this blank line signals the end of the headers
        out.println("");
        out.flush();
        // Send the HTML page
        out.print("<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<head>\n<title>Just Pic</title>\n<meta charset=\"UTF-8\">\n</head>\n<body>\n<img src=\"/images/th.jpg\"/>\n</body>\n</html>");
        out.flush();
    }
}
```

see the if clause that responds to the requests that start with /server.
the follow the code to where it handles the request.
it returns the files as a file transporter.
so the address here "server/image.jpg" will be a address that you give in regular programming in java. this address is from the root of your project.
mention that this code must have a main to use the class.
this works perfect for me.

Answer (score 0):

Place the image file next to your .html file and just use `src="image.jpg"` (relative path).
Use this for educational purposes only.

Answer (score -1):

I was looking for one answer and every where I found impossible, but i got the answer here:

https://superuser.com/questions/224500/how-to-display-local-images-in-chrome-using-file-protocol

works very good on chrome .

Answer (score -3):

Okay, you can't just let somebody else acess your local file system! You would need a server-service like Apache, let your computer run 24h a day, make sure it wont overheat, care for good security and much more to make that even possible. And because server-administration is expensive and time-consuming, most people let the pro's host our stuff for us (Webhosting).

In conclusion, if you don't want to run your own server, it's much easier to just upload it to your webhoster of choice.

Comment: -1: that doesn't really answer the question (despite being true)

Comment: Probably would have been better suited as a comment... :)

Comment: I interpreted the question the same way he did, because the asker said "without uploading it".

Comment: So the very short answer would be: You'd need to run your own server (e.g. with Apache) and then reference the image with your computer's IP. :)