# How to access local assets from a remote URL in Android WebView?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, assets, android-assets

To load an asset in HTML, I am using the URL `file:///android_asset/my_image.png`.
It works when I am loading HTML locally, for instance, using a `WebView.loadData()` method.

However, I am unable to load a local asset from a remote web site, for instance, when I load a page using `WebView.loadUrl("http://example.com/my_page.html")`. It shows the page, but the image is not loaded.

How can I fix this problem?

**UPDATE:**

tarkeshwar mentioned that it is not possible because of security reasons. I understand when you open a web page in a browser, then you as a user are unable to control what the web page is accessing. And it is also a bit different to access local file system when you may read sensitive data of the user. Here I would like just to access application assets.

A workaround could be, to download the page and load it into the `WebView` using `loadData()` method. But there might be some security switch to allow `WebView` to access local assets.

**UPDATE2:**
I need to support Android 2.3+.

Comment: Found a solution ever??

Answer (score 1):

You can't link to a local resource from an external page. That is due to security reasons.

See Pekka's answer for a similar question: [How to show local picture in web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908171/how-to-show-local-picture-in-web-page)

Answer (score 1):

Extend WebViewClient and override shouldInterceptRequest to load the file locally.  The urls would all appear remote but you can selectively load which every you need.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldInterceptRequest(android.webkit.WebView, java.lang.String)

Also answered here: 
[webview shouldinterceptrequest example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8273991/webview-shouldinterceptrequest-example)

Comment: Yes, unfortunately this requires API 11.

Comment: The only way to do it in earlier versions is to, like you said, download the page and load it as a string locally, so that it can access local resources.  That is an option I considered for what I'm doing but I chose instead to require API 11.  The JavaScript in API <11 is missing key functions as well.