# webview shouldinterceptrequest example

Tags: android, webview

I need to know how does the `shouldinterceptrequest` work. I don't know how to create and handle this method to read and replace the CSS link. Thank you!

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Well, the short answer is that it works quite similar to `shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)`, as illustrated in the [WebView tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html).

To get you started, see the code below. You simply override the `shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url)` method of your WebViewClient. Obviously you don't have to do that inline, but for the sake of compactness that's what I did:

```
    WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest (final WebView view, String url) {
            if (url.contains(".css")) {
                return getCssWebResourceResponseFromAsset();
            } else {
                return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, url);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Return WebResourceResponse with CSS markup from a String. 
         */
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        private WebResourceResponse getCssWebResourceResponseFromString() {
            return getUtf8EncodedCssWebResourceResponse(new ByteArrayInputStream("body { background-color: #F781F3; }".getBytes()));
        }

        /**
         * Return WebResourceResponse with CSS markup from an asset (e.g. "assets/style.css"). 
         */
        private WebResourceResponse getCssWebResourceResponseFromAsset() {
            try {
                return getUtf8EncodedCssWebResourceResponse(getAssets().open("style.css"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return null;
            }
        }

        /**
         * Return WebResourceResponse with CSS markup from a raw resource (e.g. "raw/style.css"). 
         */
        private WebResourceResponse getCssWebResourceResponseFromRawResource() {
            return getUtf8EncodedCssWebResourceResponse(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.style));
        }

        private WebResourceResponse getUtf8EncodedCssWebResourceResponse(InputStream data) {
            return new WebResourceResponse("text/css", "UTF-8", data);
        }

    });

    webview.loadUrl("http://stackoverflow.com");
```

Catch the loading of the css file and return your own [`WebResourceResponse`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebResourceResponse.html) containing the data you want to load in stead.

Do note that this method requires **API level 11**.

If you want to do something similar for Android 2.x, you might want to try using the earlier mentioned `shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)` to avoid loading the page, fetch it manually, replace the reference to the css file with your own, and finally call `loadData(String data, String mimeType, String encoding)`  (or `loadDataWithBaseURL(String baseUrl, String data, String mimeType, String encoding, String historyUrl)`) on the WebView, passing in the manipulated html content as a string.

Before:

[image: Before]

After:

[image: After]

Comment: So how ho do I replace the css link in my aspx file with a local one and put in the return webresourceresponse.

Comment: Well, you don't actually replace the css link in the aspx file, but whenever the referenced css file is loaded, you intercept it and in stead return your own css content. I extended the code in my answer with an example. I haven't actually tried it, but looking at the documentation it should be somewhat like that. Note that in stead of using a string with the css markup, you could also load a file from the SD card or resources and pass that along as InputStream.

Comment: I tried something like this to read css from a local file:  

        InputStream im = null;
        File file = new File("file:///android_asset/android.css");
   try {
    im = new FileInputStream(file);
   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}

Unfortunately it does not load the data of the file. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Sorry for getting back this late - it's been hectic at work. I tidied up the code a bit and added a bunch of examples that illustrate how to use the `shouldInterceptRequest` method. Using these, I had no problems at all to catch SO's css file and in stead load up my own containing nothing more than a nice pink background. See added screenshots :) I suggest you breakpoint your own code and retry loading your asset as illustrated in my example above.

Comment: MH thanks a lot. my local css works now perfect with the shouldinterceptmethod. But now I struggle with appending html tags specific javascript(combination of css and jquery) to the webview. Do you have any idea? Thank you

Comment: You could potentially inject bit 'n pieces of Javascript as outlined [here](http://lexandera.com/2009/01/injecting-javascript-into-a-webview/). However, if your plan is to make a lot of modifications to a document, I'd say it's better practice to fetch up the source apriori, modify it whatever way you want (preferably using one of the many HTML/XML parsers 'out there') and finally feed it to the WebView. That's the only way you'll have full control over the document's source...

Comment: Is there any possibility to get the code from the page loaded in webview. to parse seems to much for me. i just want to do some style modifications.

Comment: There is no convenience method to get the source code of the page loaded. There is a [workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376471/how-do-i-get-the-web-page-contents-from-a-webview) using the same approach as linked in my previous comment, but the downside is it'll effectively make the webview load twice for a single page (although it's rendered only the second time). This may be sufficient for your specific case, although I don't really see the benefits over first fetching the page, manipulating it and then load it up in the webview. Totally up to you.

Comment: hi,I had try to use shouldOverrideUrlLoading to replace the url, the it can't work at 2.3

Comment: @atian25: Yes, `shouldInterceptRequest()` wasn't available until API level 11 (Honeycomb, Android 3.0). The best next thing on older platforms is `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()`, as already mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @MH. yes, I had try, but the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` don't trigger.

Comment: I dont recommend using `StringBufferInputStream` anymore, its deprecated and it produces bad results. Do `InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(string.getBytes());` instead

Answer (score 3):

this might be also interesting for you. It reads files from specific folders and if a request is incoming with this filename it uses the file from the asset folder and not that from web.

```
    //get list of files of specific asset folder
    private ArrayList listAssetFiles(String path) {

        List myArrayList = new ArrayList();
        String [] list;
        try {
            list = getAssets().list(path);
            for(String f1 : list){
                myArrayList.add(f1);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return (ArrayList) myArrayList;
    }

    //get mime type by url
    public String getMimeType(String url) {
        String type = null;
        String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url);
        if (extension != null) {
            if (extension.equals("js")) {
                return "text/javascript";
            }
            else if (extension.equals("woff")) {
                return "application/font-woff";
            }
            else if (extension.equals("woff2")) {
                return "application/font-woff2";
            }
            else if (extension.equals("ttf")) {
                return "application/x-font-ttf";
            }
            else if (extension.equals("eot")) {
                return "application/vnd.ms-fontobject";
            }
            else if (extension.equals("svg")) {
                return "image/svg+xml";
            }
            type = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
        }
        return type;
    }

    //return webresourceresponse
    public WebResourceResponse loadFilesFromAssetFolder (String folder, String url) {
        List myArrayList = listAssetFiles(folder);
        for (Object str : myArrayList) {
            if (url.contains((CharSequence) str)) {
                try {
                    Log.i(TAG2, "File:" + str);
                    Log.i(TAG2, "MIME:" + getMimeType(url));
                    return new WebResourceResponse(getMimeType(url), "UTF-8", getAssets().open(String.valueOf(folder+"/" + str)));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    //@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(final WebView view, String url) {
        //Log.i(TAG2, "SHOULD OVERRIDE INIT");
        //String url = webResourceRequest.getUrl().toString();
        String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url);
        //I have some folders for files with the same extension
        if (extension.equals("css") || extension.equals("js") || extension.equals("img")) {
            return loadFilesFromAssetFolder(extension, url);
        }
        //more possible extensions for font folder
        if (extension.equals("woff") || extension.equals("woff2") || extension.equals("ttf") || extension.equals("svg") || extension.equals("eot")) {
            return loadFilesFromAssetFolder("font", url);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: shouldInterceptRequest is deprecated and if use new method then got " must not be null" error.

Comment: nice solution but its better u put complete code ... webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {...