# How can I get the JSON response of a POST request in a WebView?

Tags: android, json, post, android-webview

I've got a `WebView` with html containing a form (post). When clicking some submit button I get a JSON response.

How can I get this JSON?

If I don't intercept the request the json is displayed on the webview, so I guess I should use `shouldInterceptRequest` (I'm using API 12), but I don't know how to get the json in it.

Or maybe there's a better way, like intercepting the response instead of the request?

```
mWebView.loadUrl(myURL);  

isPageLoaded = false; // used because the url is the same for the response

mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest (WebView view, String url) {

        if(isPageLoaded){
            // get the json
            return null;
        }
        else return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, url);
    }

    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        isPageLoaded = true;
    }
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should override the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` method of `WebViewClient`

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url) {

    if(flag) { 

            URL aURL = new URL(url); 
            URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection(); 
            conn.connect(); 
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream(); 
            // read inputstream to get the json..
            ...
            ...
            return true;
    }

    return false
}

@override
public void onPageFinished (WebView view, String url) {
    if (url contains "form.html") {
        flag = true;
    }
}
```

Also take a look at this [How do I get the web page contents from a WebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376471/how-do-i-get-the-web-page-contents-from-a-webview)

Comment: It does not work because the url is the same as the one with the form, and with your solution I get the html with the form. Instead of intercepting the request, I should intercept the response before displaying it in the webview, or send the request with the post params...

Comment: You should ignore the form page and catch the next page loading... The doc says "Gives the host application a chance to take over the control when a new url is about to be loaded in the current WebView." So you should set a flag when form load completes, and catch the immediate next loading that happens..

Comment: Dont compare the url.. set a flag to know when the form is loading and when json is loading..

Comment: The flag ´isPageLoaded´ does exactly what you say: when true I'll get the json. The url is the same: the form is sent with POST data. Also I must use `shouldInterceptRequest` because shouldOverrideUrlLoading is never called.

Comment: Ok.. but you cannot use `shouldInterceptRequest` coz its post data. and u need to intercept response..

Comment: Any way to intercept the response?

Comment: Look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376471/how-do-i-get-the-web-page-contents-from-a-webview

Comment: But u get the data only after its loaded in the webview.. you can hide it in onPageStarted

Comment: How do you intercept the request and respinses made from within a webpage? Some sites such has gmail do background requests and it is impossible to get this information?

Comment: This method complained on 4.4 level about network connection on main thread             conn.connect(); 
That line. I have posted my solution below.

Comment: Came here with the same problem - get response json after post request. Saw accepted+awarded answer which is not answer at all ><

Answer (score 9):

Here is how i achieved this as the method mentioned started to complain about UI thread network connection.

**Using ChromeWebView Client and console log the output**

```
    public void OnSignUp_Click(View v) {
    WebView mWebview = new WebView(this);

    mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // enable javascript

    final Activity activity = this;

    mWebview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage cmsg)
        {

                /* process JSON */
            cmsg.message();
            return true;

        }
    });

    mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                String description, String failingUrl) {
            Log.e("Load Signup page", description);
            Toast.makeText(
                    activity,
                    "Problem loading. Make sure internet connection is available.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl("javascript:console.log(document.body.getElementsByTagName('pre')[0].innerHTML);");
        }
    });

    mWebview.loadUrl("https://yourapp.com/json");

}
```

Hope it helps others.

Comment: This is by far the easiest solutions and the one that actually worked for me, for catching a redirected SAML JSON response. Additional benefit: Extremely simple and no Networking on UI exception.

Comment: It works only if a web page prints messages in a log. It doesn't get POST request.

Answer (score -1):

> Well, the short answer is that it works quite similar to
>   shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url), as illustrated in
>   the WebView tutorial.
>
> To get you started, see the code below. You simply override the
>   shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url) method of your
>   WebViewClient. Obviously you don't have to do that inline, but for the
>   sake of compactness that's what I did:

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8273991/webview-shouldinterceptrequest-example).