# Updated: Android + PhoneGap intercept URL (equivalent of iOS shouldStartLoadWithRequest)

Tags: android, cordova

The [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12601491/android-phonegap-intercept-url-equivalent-of-ios-shouldstartloadwithrequest%20original%20question's)'s answers are **out of date** so I am asking it again:

I need to allow navigation from a remote resource `https` url to a `file` url. To do this on iOS I redirect navigation from `https://localhost/*` to `file:///*`

I do this on iOS by implementing the delegate method:

```
 - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType;
```

What is the equivalent of this in the current version of Cordova.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android + PhoneGap intercept URL (equivalent of iOS shouldStartLoadWithRequest)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12601491/android-phonegap-intercept-url-equivalent-of-ios-shouldstartloadwithrequest)

Comment: The original's answers are out of date. It is a duplicate, I linked directly to it.

Comment: where is the outdated part?

Comment: `CordovaWebViewClient` no longer exists as a class and there is no method `setWebViewClient` on `this.appView` anymore

Comment: any god old fashioned `WebViewClient` will do (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer my own question. The current solution is the following code:

```
@Override
protected void init() {
    super.init();

    final SystemWebView webView = (SystemWebView) appView.getEngine().getView();

    webView.setWebViewClient(new SystemWebViewClient((SystemWebViewEngine) this.appView.getEngine()) {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url.startsWith("https://localhost")) {
                view.loadUrl(url.replace("https://localhost", "file:///"));
                return true;
            }
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: I am curious, is SystemWebView extending WebView and in what package is it?

Comment: `org.apache.cordova.engine.SystemWebView extends WebView implements CordovaWebViewEngine.EngineView`

Comment: Thanks, was indeed what I've thought. Now would be of interest what fancy stuff a EngineView is offering, but I 'll see for myself.

Answer (score 0):

Get hold of the `View` in the `CordovaActivity` (which is a `WebView`, so you can cast it to a `WebView`) and set a `WebViewClient` to it (e.g. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html)
containing the logic you want it to have (should be similar to the linked question)