# How to modify content before rendering in Android WebView?

Tags: android, webview

I am making a custom simple web browser for Android and needed to capture the content of every page the user browses and manipulate it **before rendering** so that it displays as expected.

I don't want to break user login state and interaction, so I don't want to intercept the POST request or cookies.

So far as I know, I can put the content with `loadDataWithBaseURL()`.
However, to make a better user experience, I wan to get the content and manipulate before the user sees it, and if possible, before images being downloaded (like `DOMReady` in JS), but had no clue how to do it.

What is the best place to listen to, and how can I get the current `webview` content?

Since I am new to Android development, I was looking for a good advice for the solution.
Thanks.

Comment: There is a way to get content using `HttpClient`, but this is not good for *cookies*, and  *POSTs*.

http://lexandera.com/2009/01/extracting-html-from-a-webview/ suggested using `onPageFinished()` and JavaScript to feed the content to the Activity.

But I was wondering if there is a better way without JS.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `shouldInterceptRequest` method. there is an example:

[webview shouldinterceptrequest example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8273991/webview-shouldinterceptrequest-example)

Hope this is useful.