# IBM Worklight 6.0 - "Could not find class 'android.webkit.WebResourceResponse'" on Android 2.2

Tags: android, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

After migrating to Worklight v6.0 I get this error on old Android 2.2 device:

> E/dalvikvm(xxx): Could not find class
>   'android.webkit.WebResourceResponse', referenced from method
>   org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebViewClient.getWhitelistResponse

Comment: Do you plan to upgrade cordova version any time soon?

Comment: Have you tried With Worklight 6.1?

Answer (score 0):

Is this crashing your application or just being printed to the LogCat?

This is fixed in Cordova 2.7.
Worklight 6.0 currently uses Cordova 2.6.

For more information: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-3504

> In CordovaWebViewClient.java, android.webkit.WebResourceResponse is
>   imported and used by the methods shouldInterceptRequest and
>   getWhitelistResponse. But since android.webkit.WebResourceResponse is
>   only available on devices >= API Level 11, this causes cordova apps to
>   crash on devices at a lower API Level like my Samsung Galaxy S.

Some more from Stackoverflow:

- [Could not find class 'android.webkit.WebResourceResponse' when running HelloCordova on Android 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16444996/could-not-find-class-android-webkit-webresourceresponse-when-running-hellocord)
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-3041

Comment: migrating from WL 5.0.6 dojo app, tested on emuluator and device both api 8.

Comment: In fact I saw the solutions before, But I am developing a simple application using worklight, I do not make use of apache cordova

Comment: Cordova is in the core of the project even if you're not making use of it. Worklight does.

Comment: @user2536334, can you upload to somewhere your Worklight project that is crashing when installed on a device? Are you an IBMer?