# Worklight 6.0 - how to create and deploy dojo enable worklight hybrid application for android 2.2 using dojo 1.9 and worklight 6.0

Tags: android, dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

I am new to both dojo and worklight and was trying to develope a sample hybrid application using dojo toolkit. However this sample application works on simulators but not works on avd using android environment 2.2.Can anyone please tell me the steps/modifications to follow to create and deploy a sample dojo enabled hybrid application?

Comment: Try what is being mentioned in the following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17603370/dojo-doesnt-work-on-android-in-the-worklight-6-0-0-version

Answer (score -1):

Are you probably hitting this? [IBM Worklight 6.0 - "Could not find class 'android.webkit.WebResourceResponse'" on Android 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17389775/ibm-worklight-6-0-could-not-find-class-android-webkit-webresourceresponse)

It seems there is a limitation on Android 2.2 support for Worklight 6.0.

Comment: not the same issue... it will work on the avd, the actual problem is due to Dojo, not Cordova (that one, is about crashing in a device). Please remove...