# IBM Worklight 6.0 - scriptError in dojo.js:21

Tags: android, dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

I have created a simple application using the bundled Dojo v1.9 and upon running it device or emulator, I am getting the following error:

> *07-08 05:38:17.429: E/Web Console(530): Error: scriptError at file:///data/data/com.WorklightApp/files/www/default/dojo/dojo.js:21*

These are the steps that I took:

1. Create a Worklight project and application (with Dojo)
2. Add a simple dojo tag on the main page
3. Add the Android environment
4. Build All and Deploy
5. Run on device and/or emulator

The dojo components will not appear; instead I get the above mentioned error.
The application does however work correctly when previewed in Worklight Console.

Is there anything that I must do in Worklight v6.0 to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if any of the following answers to questions about the same issue help you out:

- [IBM Worklight 6.0 - Unable to run sample hybrid worklight app using dojo toolkit for android environment on avd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17543927/ibm-worklight-6-0-unable-to-run-sample-hybrid-worklight-app-using-dojo-toolkit)
- [Worklight core-web-layer.js errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546952/worklight-core-web-layer-js-errors)