# Is there a way to pass an arraybuffer from javascript to java on Android?

Tags: java, javascript, android, binding

I'm stuck for a moment on this case.

I have a webview on `Android 4.4.3` where I have a webapp who has `float32array` containing binary data. I would like to pass that `array` to the Java Android via a function binded with `JavascriptInterface`. 
However, it seems like in Java, I can only pass primitive types like `String`, `int` etc...

Is there a way to give to Java this arrayBuffer ?

Thank you !

Comment: Can you create the array on a server and have the Java code in your android app request it via HTTP?

Answer (score 25):

Ok, so following a chat with Google engineering and after reading the code I've reached the following conclusions.

#### Passing binary data efficiently is impossible

It is impossible to pass binary data efficiently between JavaScript and Java through a @JavascriptInterface:

On the Java side:

```
@JavascriptInterface
void onBytes(byte[] bytes) {
   // bytes available here
}
```

And on the JavaScript side:

```
var byteArray = new Uint8Array(buffer);
var arr = new Uint8Array(byteArray.length);
for(var i = 0; i < byteArray.length; i++) {
  arr[i] = byteArray[i];
}
javaObject.onBytes(arr);
```

In the code above (from my old answer) and in Alex's - [the conversion performed for the array](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/content/browser/android/java/gin_java_script_to_java_types_coercion.cc?q=gin_java_scr&sq=package:chromium&l=573) is brutal:

```
case JavaType::TypeArray:
  if (value->IsType(base::Value::Type::DICTIONARY)) {
    result.l = CoerceJavaScriptDictionaryToArray(
        env, value, target_type, object_refs, error);
  } else if (value->IsType(base::Value::Type::LIST)) {
    result.l = CoerceJavaScriptListToArray(
        env, value, target_type, object_refs, error);
  } else {
    result.l = NULL;
  }
  break;
```

Which in turn [coerces every array element to a Java object](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/content/browser/android/java/gin_java_script_to_java_types_coercion.cc?q=gin_java_scr&sq=package:chromium&l=470):

```
for (jsize i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
    const base::Value* value_element = null_value.get();
    list_value->Get(i, &value_element);
    jvalue element = CoerceJavaScriptValueToJavaValue(
        env, value_element, target_inner_type, false, object_refs, error);
    SetArrayElement(env, result, target_inner_type, i, element);
```

So, for a `1024 * 1024 * 10` `Uint8Array` - ten million Java objects are created and destroyed on each pass resulting in 10 seconds of CPU time on my emulator.

#### Creating an HTTP server

One thing we tried was creating an HTTP server and `POST`ing the result to it via an `XMLHttpRequest`. This worked - but ended up costing about 200ms of latency and also introduced a [nasty memory leak](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=749482&can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&groupby=&sort=).

#### MessageChannels are slow

Android API 23 added support for [`MessageChannel`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MessageChannel)s, which can be used via [`createWebMessageChannel()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#createWebMessageChannel()) as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41753104/how-do-you-use-webmessageport-as-an-alternative-to-addjavascriptinterface). This is very slow, still serializes with GIN (like the `@JavascriptInterface` method) and incurs additional latency. I was not able to get this to work with reasonable performance.

It is worth mentioning that Google said they believe this is the way forward and hopes to promote message channels over `@JavascriptInterface` at some point.

#### Passing a string works

After reading the conversion code - one can see (and this was confirmed by Google) that the only way to avoid many conversions is to pass a `String` value. This only goes through:

```
case JavaType::TypeString: {
  std::string string_result;
  value->GetAsString(&string_result);
  result.l = ConvertUTF8ToJavaString(env, string_result).Release();
  break;
}
```

Which converts the result once to UTF8 and then again to a Java string. This still means the data (10MB in this case) is copied three times - but it is possible to pass 10MB of data in "only" 60ms - which is a lot more reasonable than the 10 seconds the above array method takes.

[Petka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/995876/esailija) came up with the idea of using [8859](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859) encoding which can convert a single byte to a single letter. Unfortunately it is not supported in JavaScript's [TextDecoder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextDecoder/TextDecoder) API - so [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) which is another 1 byte encoding can be used instead.

On the JavaScript side one can do:

```
var a = new Uint8Array(1024 * 1024 * 10); // your buffer
var b = a.buffer
// actually windows-1252 - but called iso-8859 in TextDecoder
var e = new TextDecoder("iso-8859-1"); 
var dec = e.decode(b);
proxy.onBytes(dec); // this is in the Java side.
```

Then, in the Java side:

```
@JavascriptInterface
public void onBytes(String dec) throws UnsupportedEncodingException
    byte[] bytes = dec.getBytes("windows-1252");
    // work with bytes here
}
```

Which runs in about 1/8th the time of direct serialization. It's still not very fast (since the string is padded to 16 bits instead of 8, then through UTF8 and then to UTF16 again). However, it runs in reasonable speed compared to the alternative.

After speaking with the relevant parties who are maintaining this code - they told me that it's as good as it can get with the current API. I was told I'm the first person to ask for this (fast JavaScript to Java serialization).

Comment: I'd like to thank CommonWare, Petka and Chromium's Tarbo for helping me and directing me in figuring this out :)

Comment: I can't get it working as fast with those encodings, the fastest way is using utf-8. It also takes 150-300ms for 3MB. Do you know why this is the case?

Comment: What device did you test on? UTF8 is 300ms which is much slower - are you testing on really old devices or with a text encoding polyfill

Comment: I'm testing on an AndroidTV Nougat, so it's not really old. When I used fixed 1-byte character encodings it took almost as much as copying an array (a couple of seconds).

Comment: Thanks Benjamin. For the Java -> Javascript direction, the WebViewClient has a shouldInterceptRequest method that can just provide a stream of bytes as the response (and be read as an ArrayBuffer on the JS side from a fetch). Unfortunately for JS -> Java it doesn't seem as helpful, as the body of the request is not available in that function. I was thinking it might have allowed your POST method to work with hopefully lower latency and without the need for an HTTP server, but no luck.

Comment: As noted below by @张浩然, both iso-8859-1 and windows-1252 have undefined characters. These really shouldn't be used.

Comment: They do however decode just fine between JavaScript and Java and it's the only solution with reasonable performance, it is an order of magnitude faster than base64 encode/decode

Comment: Have you tested this for every possible byte value? A (correct) alternative which works and is just as fast is "x-user-defined". The byte value will be on the low-order 8-bits of each character. You can then use the string directly (no decoding, and avoids another copy), or if needed use the (deprecated) getBytes that simply takes the low-order 8-bits (again this should be faster than decoding).

Comment: I did check every possible byte value (And shipped it to production where it moved hundreds of terabytes every day a year ago). I don't think that JavaScript encoding APIs actually do x-user-defined, might be interesting to check.

Comment: Ben this fix was AMAZING. You're a stud

Comment: Is createWebMessageChannel still slow in 2020?

Comment: @tangobravo, can you provide an example for the Java -> Javascript usecase?
i.e. how to pass arraybuffer from Android to Javascript using the shouldInterceptRequest

Comment: @tangobravo Would this work for large files (GB of data)?

Comment: @AvnerMoshkovitz I don't have an example to hand. Google can find some examples, eg: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8273991/webview-shouldinterceptrequest-example

It's a stream on the Java side, so if you read it with a ReadableStream on the JS side I'd expect it to work. Reading the whole thing into an ArrayBuffer will likely hit problems. You'll need to try it to see. My use case was trying to send camera frames across from the native side (so around 1M data each time, but at 30 FPS). It didn't hit the performance I needed but can't remember if that was due to latency or throughput.

Answer (score 4):

It is pretty simple

Init section

```
 JavaScriptInterface jsInterface = new JavaScriptInterface(this);
 webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 webView.addJavascriptInterface(jsInterface, "JSInterface");
```

JavaScriptInterface

```
public class JavaScriptInterface {
        private Activity activity;

        public JavaScriptInterface(Activity activiy) {
            this.activity = activiy;
        }
        @JavascriptInterface
        public void putData(byte[] bytes){
            //do whatever
        }
    }
```

Js section

```
<script>
  function putAnyBinaryArray(arr) {
        var uint8 = Uint8Array.from(arr);
        window.JSInterface.putData(uint8);
  };
</script>
```

TypedArray.from polyfill if need : https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/from

Comment: Actually, there is a better way - to use a MessagePort - which avoids the copy in this answer - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#createWebMessageChannel() - https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/web-messaging.html#messagechannel

Comment: Meaning, it can potentially be twice as fast. This was still the best answer when the bounty expired - so cheers. If you want to update your answer I would appreciate not having to post another one.

Comment: So, turns out this doesn't _really_ work, it crashes the Chrome process if you try to pass more than 10mb and it will take 10s to pass 10mb (and 1s to pass 1mb)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum try to slice your array by 1mb. The operation of passing data to android or js it is a heavy process. You really not pass a data, you creating a copy of your data. So it takes twice the memory.

Comment: It looks like it's doing string conversion or is otherwise slow :( If I have a 10mb array it takes over 10 seconds to pass which is ridiculous since it's more than it takes to download.

Comment: I fixed it, I'll post a working answer later this week

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I look forward to your post:)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I look forward to your post :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45506857/1348195

Answer (score 3):

Serialise your data into a string, then unserialize in your app.

Comment: Seems like Cordova does the same.

Answer (score 2):

Cloning the ArrayBuffer makes it work - something about a TypedArray backed with an ArrayBuffer doesn't marshall well into Android.

If you copy your ArrayBuffer into a new TypedArray you can avoid the expensive serialization overhead.

On the reader:

```
@JavascriptInterface
void onBytes(byte[] bytes) {
   // bytes available here
}
```

And on the JS side:

```
var byteArray = new Uint8Array(buffer);
var arr = new Uint8Array(byteArray.length);
for(var i = 0; i < byteArray.length; i++) {
  arr[i] = byteArray[i];
}
javaObject.onBytes(arr);
```

Works perfectly fine :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want **Sync** call, just use base64 encode & decode: ([Convert base64 string to ArrayBuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21797299/convert-base64-string-to-arraybuffer/54123275#54123275))

```
@JavascriptInterface
void onBytes(String base64) {
    // decode here
}
```

If you want **Async** call:

You can create http server in Android appliction, and then use "xhr" or "fetch" in javascript side to send binary or string async

---

**And don't use "iso-8859-1" or "windows-1252" mentioned above, it's dangerous !!!**
"iso-8859-1" has undefined code which can't be decode between javascript and java. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Comment: Using iso-8859-1/windows-1252 is a bad idea, but x-user-defined works.
Have you compared the performance of this vs base64?

Answer (score 0):

the code linked in the second answer https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:content/browser/android/java/gin_java_script_to_java_types_coercion.cc;l=628?q=gin_java_scr&ss=chromium

doesn't actually understand TypedArrays (it looks like it does because it says TypeArray but, everything in that file is TypeXZY)

So I can definitely imagine that it's faster to copy a string.
However, there is no reason that it shouldn't be able to pass a typed array without copying, or at least with just a single raw copy.

It would require a patch to chromium though.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, app tranfers blob data each other without a http server, so there's no choice but to send arrayBuffer to javainterface, as follows:

```
//javascript
if ((window as any)?.JsBridge?.downloadFile) {
      file.arrayBuffer().then(arr => {
        (window as any)?.JsBridge?.downloadFile(new Uint8Array(arr), filename)
      })
}
//java
@JavascriptInterface
public void downloadFile(byte[] bytes, String filename) {
    NativeApi.log("downloadFile", filename + "," + bytes.length);
}
```

by the way, the file limit to 10M, toast something after asyncTask processed!