# Inject JS/CSS before WebView show up

Tags: android, android-webview, javascript-injection

I've seen several questions on this but all of the solutions didn't work for me. For a client we have to develop an app that actually does nothing except of showing a `WebView` and a native `DrawerLayout`. However, we only have their mobile webpage (with a menu, etc.). So we have to hide some elements. It is very important that the existing stylesheets stay the same, just some other `CSS` rules are added.

What I've tried so far:

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        if (!mErrorOccured && !noConnectionAvailable) {
            injectCSS();
        }

        mainActivity.hideLoadingScreen();
}
```

With this Injection:

```
// Inject CSS method: read style.css/readmode.css from assets folder
// Append stylesheet to document head
private void injectCSS() {
    try {
        Activity activity = (Activity) mContext;
        SharedPreferences sharPref = activity.getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFERENCE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Boolean isReadMode = sharPref.getBoolean(Constants.READMODE_KEY, false);

        InputStream inputStream;

        if (isReadMode) {
            inputStream = activity.getAssets().open("readmode.css");
        } else {
            inputStream = activity.getAssets().open("style.css");
        }

        byte[] buffer = new byte[inputStream.available()];
        inputStream.read(buffer);
        inputStream.close();
        String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(buffer, Base64.NO_WRAP);
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() {" +
                    "var parent = document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0);" +
                    "var style = document.createElement('style');" +
                    "style.type = 'text/css';" +
                    // Tell the browser to BASE64-decode the string into your script !!!
                    "style.innerHTML = window.atob('" + encoded + "');" +
                    "parent.appendChild(style);" +
                    "Android.injectCSS('Works!');})()");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

I've also tried to add a JavaScript Interface that uses the `Android.injectCSS('Works!');` of the JavaScript above combined with:

```
@JavascriptInterface
public void injectCSS(String toast) {
    Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    mMainActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mMainFragment.unhideWebView();
        }
    });
}
```

And:

```
public void unhideWebView() {
    webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

However, there is always a delay before the elements of the web page are hidden. I've also tried to use `Jsoup`. First this threw an `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. After I've tried to use it with an AsyncTask, it was not possible to change the `WebView` on `onPostExecute()` because this handling must be on the main thread. Even using a `runOnUiThrad()` did not help calling `loadData()` on the `WebView` with the new loaded data.

Is there any way to inject CSS/JS before the `WebView` shows up?

Comment: Take a look at my answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42471990/android-how-can-i-know-css-injection-is-complete?noredirect=1#comment72084584_42471990

Comment: In addition to that you can intercept loading of one of the css files like described in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8273991/webview-shouldinterceptrequest-example. But instead of replacing it's data - simply append it with your additional css rules