# Ways for analysis of WebResourceResponse

Tags: android, webview

I want to analyze all requests sent from WebView.
For this, I have `WebViewClient` and `shouldInterceptRequest` overridden.
I can see requests, but I would like to see what `webView` will receive in response. I need this for analysis, I do not have need to change response.
Line bellow gives null,

```
WebResourceResponse response = super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, request);
```

I know, that `shouldInterceptRequest()` return null, means that no one intercept the request, and the `webView` will load the origin `URL`.
But, I would like to see this `WebResourceResponse` and do not implement it by myself.Thanks!!

Comment: Have look [webview shouldinterceptrequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8273991/webview-shouldinterceptrequest-example)

Comment: @HemantParmar. Thanks for your proposition, but I want to see WebResourceResponse which web view will use. Method shouldInterceptRequest gives the possibility to make own WebResourceResponse, but I can't see a way to see and analyze actual WebResourceResponse. it always null. Thanks.