# Work in WebViewClient.shouldInterceptRequest will lead the UI no response a little time

Tags: android, multithreading, android-webview, picasso, freeze

I want to use Picasso to load image in webview. I found the code below. The code is work properly but if the html have many images, which will lead the UI no response a little time.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url) {
        final String mime = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(url);
        if (mime == null || !mime.startsWith("image")) {
            return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, url);
        }
        try {
            final Bitmap image = Picasso.with(context).load(url).get();
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            if (mime.endsWith("jpeg")) {
                image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
            } else if (mime.endsWith("png")) {
                image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
            } else {
                return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, url);
            }
            InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());
            return new WebResourceResponse(mime, "UTF-8", in);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to load image", e);
            return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, url);
        }
    }
});
```

I found the following code will lead the UI no response.

```
Picasso.get()
```

and

```
Bitmap.compress()
```

For solve UI no response problem when `Picasso.get()` call in `WebViewClient.shouldInterceptRequest()`, I use `Picasso.into()` to avoid thread block, but the method can’t call in `WebViewClient.shouldInterceptRequest()`, that will throw exception “java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method call should happen from the main thread.”

```
final PipedOutputStream out = new PipedOutputStream();
PipedInputStream is = new PipedInputStream(out);
NetworkUtils.getPicassoInstance(getContext())
        .load(urlStr)
        .into(new Target() {
            @Override
            public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                if (bitmap != null) {
                    try {
                        if (mime.endsWith("jpeg")) {
                            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
                        } else if (mime.endsWith("png")) {
                            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Because of `Bitmap.compress` method will waste many resource, so I use another way to convert bitmap. I use the following code to convert `Bitmap` to `InputStream`. But use this way will lead the WebView can’t show images properly, images converted by ByteBuffer will display as error image.

```
int byteSize = bitmap.getRowBytes() * bitmap.getHeight();
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(byteSize);
bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(byteBuffer);  
byte[] byteArray = byteBuffer.array();
ByteArrayInputStream bs = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);
```

How to solve the problem?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you specify the need of it ? Are you downloading a image from WebView ? Also Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/8274881/4168607.

Comment: I want to use Picasso handle all of download images request in WebView.

Comment: Ok . I Already have mentioned the reason below . I think to download some resource you need to notify user that something is downloading So you have to do this on a `Thread`. I am not sure about the problem but does `DownloadManager` fits your requirements .

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. `WebViewClient.shouldInterceptRequest()` is not call on UI Thread, so I am confused why work in this method will get UI stuck. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldInterceptRequest(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.WebResourceRequest)
Because of I need caching function of Picasso, I can’t use DownloadManager.

Comment: Yeah i have gone threw the doc seems you are right . But i am confused since we have to return a type from `shouldInterceptRequest()` then i think we should go with a seperate task . Otherwise the return will get called synchronously after finishing the task. and that will take excess time . I am Not much familiar  with `WebView`.