# part of web page loads at host

Tags: css, browser, web

I hope you are going to understand what i want to accomplish...

I have local web server with web application on it and 10 hosts. Because of poor communication link with the server, I would like to know is it possible to store pictures and maybe some css scripts locally to host so that browser load it from local hard drive

Answer (score 0):

This is no longer allowed due to security issues. This may be possible with a local web server though.

See: [How to show local picture in web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908171/how-to-show-local-picture-in-web-page)

Comment: i have install web server on each host, and I have added next link in html code on my main web server "http://localhost/js/java.js" so that this file is loaded from hosts web server. with mozilla firefox it works, but not with opera. probably again because of security issues, but is there any way to make it work.