# I can't get image out of "resources" folder

Tags: html

EDIT:

I need to get an image out of "resources" package, the image is in the folder `C:/folder, this code works in Explorer browser, but don't works un google chrome browser.

want my project to work on both of us.

```
<p:row>
  <p:column>
    <h:graphicImage
      url="file:///C:/test/2018/03/13/test.jpg"
      style="width: 100%;margin-top: 10%;" />
  </p:column>
</p:row>
```

I'm trying use the above code, but it doesn't work.

EDIT 2:

I tryed:

- execute Google Chrome as Administrator;
- execute chrome with permission to access files and folder using

  --allow-file-access-from-files

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I display an image from the local machine on a webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28194444/how-can-i-display-an-image-from-the-local-machine-on-a-webpage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a `file:` url to referance files on your local machine like this:

```html
<p:row>
  <p:column>
    <h:graphicImage
      url="file:///C:/test/2018/03/13/test.jpg"
      style="width: 100%;margin-top: 10%;" />
  </p:column>
</p:row>
```

Comment: Try using an `<img>` tag instead of JSF's `<h:graphicImage>` tag. It looks like `<h:graphicImage>` cannot access outside the resources folder.

Comment: In Exeplorer browser works, but in google chrome nothing... i really prefer to use google chrome.

Any suggestion?