# In high chart library how to load image from hard disk not from network?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

I am using the [highcharts library](https://www.highcharts.com/demo) to draw the graph. But I want to use the custom markers instead of predefined markers like(circle, rectangle etc). I am working in react and using the wrapper of high chart library.

```
 series: [{
        name: 'symbol name',
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, ],
        marker: {
            symbol: url('image url here');
        }
    }
```

when I mention the image URL then it loads the image from the network.
But I want to load the image of maker from the hard disk, not from internet how can I do this.

[Example is available on this link](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-marker-symbol/)

Comment: Short answer : You can't. Long answer : If you use highcharts on your computer with or without `localhost`, then you can use a picture on your computer but on a website you can't do that.

Comment: Hi Sunny, loading a image to Highcharts is the same as loading it to a website. This topic can be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908171/how-to-show-local-picture-in-web-page

Answer (score 0):

Download it (https://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/sun.png). Then for example, copy image to local website. And update URL "/image/sun.png"