# React> locale img instead image from api

Tags: weather-api

I developing a SPA with https://openweathermap.org/, so i display img with

```
<img src={`http://openweathermap.org/img/w/${data.weather[0].icon}.png`}/>
```

Instead of this, i want to display another image from my local folder.I have created utils folder with index.js and another folder named weatherIcon with icons in .svg
index.js i have

`export const getWeatherIcon = (icon) => (`/weatherIcon/${icon}.png`)`

in component i change

but nothnig display in app.

Question is: How display local image instead Api image

Comment: Duplicate.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908171/how-to-show-local-picture-in-web-page

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to use images in a React Project. Since, React follows Component architecture we have flexibility in React.
So we can represent image (if it is an SVG image) As a React Component,and import and use it directly, or we can first import an image and use it in `img` tag's `src` attribute.

Please refer to watch this article to understand better and use a approach better suiting your needs.

[betterprogramming.pub/how-to-display-images-in-react](https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-display-images-in-react-dfe22a66d5e7)

**Note:** Sometimes in NextJS projec, I observed that we have to use React Component approach when using SVG. Also, we can use images in our public folder  if they are `.png`, or `.pneg` etc and directly use absolute path to show them.

Answer (score 0):

my solution
i crated new constance

```
    const WeatherIcon = {
    "01d": "/icons/01d.svg"
   }
```

then  then import to component,

`import{ WeatherIcon }from "utils/index";`

and use in Img tags

```
<img className="weather_icon" src={WeatherIcon[data.weather[0].icon]}/>
```

thx for helping