# Can I open a local file, in Firefox, with a link link like: file:///home/user

Tags: javascript, firefox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Firefox Links to local or network pages do not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192080/firefox-links-to-local-or-network-pages-do-not-work)

Hi all,

I would like to know how can i offer users that connected in my web site (in JAVA - JSP pages) to show the contents of files in THEIR PC over Web browser.

More precisely, i want to have a button, on what when user click, it open a new TAB or new window (of the browser) with path like : file:///home/user...

I did try with my flowing snippet of codes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
[...]
   window.open("file:///home/user...");
[...]
</script>
```

this works fine when i open my html file manually with Firefox, but when i try to load it in a application server (Java EE), it doesn't work at all. I get this kind of message in my error console (of firefox):

```
Security Error: Content at http://localhost:8080/MyProject/test.jsp may not load 
or link to file:///home/user.
```

It seems to be a problem related to the security policies of Firefox, still i didn't found any issues to resolve my problem ...

Do you have any ideas about this?

Comment: Yes, that is it ! thanks hippietrail ;)

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible because of security reasons.

Comment: hi Riateche, can you develop your response please ?

Answer (score 0):

Remote pages are not allowed to link to `file://` pages because it allows attacks on the browser, and in some cases on the OS.  For example, `<img src="file:///dev/tty">` on Linux will hang the browser for most users (the few running it from a terminal will be able to recover by foregrounding it, but that's it).

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to read a local file through your web application, however, you can ask the user to upload the file first and then open it.