# Firefox doesn't show image, on IE works fine

Tags: .net, html, image, firefox, path

I'm having some problem with images on Firefox, hope you can help me.

I have a page (.aspx - VB.NET) that is a viewer of images, and I build a treeview to navigate on the folders, and buttons to pass forward through the images. My problem is that it works fine in IE, but the image doesn't show in Firefox.

I'm using a absolute path, because the image isn't on the same server as the application, and so I get the path by code-behind, and change the property of my asp.net control Image.  Like so:

```
Image.ImageUrl = "\\spoad1\Mkt\FOTOS GERAL DA FAMILIA OPTION\2005 - CONFRATERNIZAÇÃO\apng.PNG"
```

On IE, works fine; it changes the path adding the part of file:// and changes the backslash("\") into "/"

```
file://spoad1/Mkt/FOTOS%20GERAL%20DA%20FAMILIA%20OPTION/2005%20-%20CONFRATERNIZAÇÃO/apng.PNG
```

Note that the //spoad1 is the server where my image is localized.

But on Firefox, it doesn't work, and the URL of image changes a lot. Using the console error, I get this:

```
http://localhost/main/FamiliaOption/%5C%5Cspoad1%5CMkt%5CFOTOS%20GERAL%20DA%20FAMILIA%20OPTION%5C2005%20-%20CONFRATERNIZA%C3%87%C3%83O%5Capng.PNG
```

It appears that Firefox is adding the current location of my application (http://localhost/main/FamiliaOption/) and adding the URL after this. How can I get Firefox to display the URL correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this blog](http://rubenlaguna.com/wp/2007/04/20/firefox-and-file-windows-unc-paths/index.html), firefox considers UNC links to be a security threat.

There is a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192080/firefox-links-to-local-or-network-pages-do-not-work) on stackoverflow. Check the answers in that question.

Comment: Thank you, sorry the late for answering. I need to create a Virtual Directory in my IIS, so I can access it with no problems. :)

Answer (score 1):

"try to give full path i mean from the link of the image start from "http:\...." once check it"