# ASP.NET - Images Not Loading Properly on Google Chrome/Firefox?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am making a web application using ASP.NET and I noticed that only Internet Explorer loads images properly that are on my home computer (../Desktop/WebsiteImages/xxxx.jpg), whereas the images won't load on Chrome or Firefox. If I want the images to display on Google Chrome or Firefox, I have to upload the images on a web hosting site such as imgur instead of having them all on a file on my computer. Is this a known bug?

Comment: post your code, we need to know how are you calling your images

Comment: are you doing: <img src="file:///C:/... ?

Comment: Yes using <img src="file://C:/ ../Desktop/WebsiteImages/xxxx.jpg">

Answer (score 2):

> If I want the images to display on Google Chrome or Firefox, I have to
>   upload the images on a web hosting site such as imgur instead of
>   having them all on a file on my computer. Is this a known bug?

It is not a bug.

Web Server will never serve a file which is located outside of a web application *(unless you create an image handler by yourself)*.

If you are new to web application, easiest way is to place images inside `~/images/` folder inside your ASP.Net application.

Then you can call the image like this -

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/MyImage.jpg")" alt="My Image"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

showing local file like file:// is not allowed in Chrome and Firefox for security reasons by default, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192080/firefox-links-to-local-or-network-pages-do-not-work#answer-192284) shows you how to change those settings. it's not recommended to use local filepath for your image