# Firefox removes href attribute if the link doesn't start with htttp://

Tags: html, http, firefox, href, clipboard

If I paste an html link with a `href` that doesn't start with `http://` in an html editor in Chrome or Firefox, then result is not the same. Chrome keep the href attribute but Firefox removes it.

So if I paste a link (which has this source code `<a href="zotero://open-pdf/0_123456" target="_blank">Open PDF</a>`) in the HTML mode (not the source code mode) of an HTML editor in Chrome, and then them switch to the source code mode, I see the exact them source code as above. But if I paste the same link in an HTML editor in Firefox, I end up with this source code:

```
<a target="_blank">Open PDF</a>
```

The test can be done with [Quackit.com](http://www.quackit.com/html/online-html-editor/). When I start Firefox in Safe Mode, then the `href="zotero://open-pdf/0_123456"` isn't removed.

How can I paste a link in an HTML editor in Firefox when its `href` doesn't contain an `http://`?

---

More background: I am creating this link with a python script based on [HtmlClipboard](https://gist.github.com/EnoraNedelec/154b18e044148fcf637213451901f351)

---

I tried all the solution on [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192080/firefox-links-to-local-or-network-pages-do-not-work) page but without success. My issue doesn't seem to be the same. I don't have any trouble opening a local link with firefox: if I paste `zotero://open-pdf/0_123456` in the url bar, firefox open the pdf. I have trouble pasting the html link in an html editor.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firefox Links to local or network pages do not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192080/firefox-links-to-local-or-network-pages-do-not-work)

Comment: @raven: see my edit in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all, it wasn't caused by Firefox but one of my extension because the problem disappears when Firefox is in safe-mode (on Windows, `Windows + R` and enter `firefox -safe-mode`). This doesn't resolve my problem, but at least it answers this question.

Thanks to [jscher2000](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1148173) for pointing that to me.